# Hyperlink visited color

Tags: xaml, hyperlink, windows-phone

How to change color of hyperlink after clicking on hyperlink (visited state).

I create hyperlink dynamically with next code:

1. I use Paragraph into RichTextBox in XAML
2. I fill this TShortName object in code behind with:

   TShortName.Inlines.Add(GetNameUrlAsLink(((MyClass)DataContext).MyProperty));
3. And finally I populate data (hyperlink) with:

   private Hyperlink GetNameUrlAsLink(string hp)
   {
   var hl = new Hyperlink
   {
       NavigateUri = new Uri(hp),
       TargetName = "_blank",
       Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(currentAccentColorHex), 
       FontSize = 20,
   };
   hl.Inlines.Add(hp);
   return hl;
   }

As a result, I get hyperlink with accent color (currentAccentColorHex). But I need to change that color when I click on link because it becomes white which is not appropriate for me at all.

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  Dim scb As New SolidColorBrush()
  scb.Color = Colors.Green
  myHyperlinkButton.Background = scb
```